how to arrange data frame that has a multiple value inside of a value?
So, I want to make a data frame that contain information needed in making a vet appointment.
Data Frame Content :
 > Pet Owner's Name
 > Pet Information
   > Pet Name
   > Pet Breed
   > Pet Age

Base on those Data Frame, I want to use the pet owner's name as the name of the Appointment (Appointment: Natasha) so that I could show an appointment information (like the pet name, breed, and age) only just by the Pet Owner's Name.
But, I'm confused on how to arrange all of those content in the Data Frame.
I tried this :
df_appt = {
    "Appointment" : [], "Pet Information" : {
        "Pet Name" : [],
        "Pet Breed" : [],
        "Pet Age" : []
        }
          }

But when I tried to upload it as Data Frame using pandas it shows an output ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering. and I could not import it as an excel file.
I tried by visioning the table first on excel like this :

But, I don't think my table is right(?)
Is there a much better or much efficient way to arrange those in a table?
And arranging it on the data frame?
notes : I can not use SQL and this data frame could hold multiple data of appointment (so it's not only for one pet owner's)

I suggest to mage "flat" dataframe and as index set the "Appointment".
For example, you have this dataframe:
  Appointment Pet Name Pet Breed  Pet Age
0        John      Bob       Dog        3
1        John     Flip    Rabbit        9
2     Natasha     Flop      Bird        1

Then you can do:
df = df.set_index("Appointment")
print(df)

            Pet Name Pet Breed  Pet Age
Appointment                            
John             Bob       Dog        3
John            Flip    Rabbit        9
Natasha         Flop      Bird        1


To select all John's pets use df.loc:
print(df.loc["John"])

Prints:
            Pet Name Pet Breed  Pet Age
Appointment                            
John             Bob       Dog        3
John            Flip    Rabbit        9

